# sending http request using method post in php to a mobile application that is using objective C (.xcode)

Tags: php, iphone, xcode

I am working on project that is taking the data from a voiceXML application and then the voiceXML application send  the variable that contains the data into a .php and I am done with that part but the problem is when I want to send the variable by sending a HTTP POST Request from .php to the mobile application which is installed on the iphone that is written using objective C programming language with an extension (.xcode), I faced a problem in receiving the variable on the mobile application,

So what I tried to do for a couple of months is to send the variable first to another .php and if it works with me, I will try to fixed the problem with mobile application.

I used httpRequest () Class - method post in order to send variable but the problem is that I don't know what to write on the other .php file to receive this variable and then display it.

This is the whole code :

```
<?php

//----------------------- Get the variable from .vxml file -----------------------------

$serverVariable = $_GET["spelling"];

//----------------------- Creation of the Database as a buffer -------------------------

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$ReceivedFlag=0;
$ReadFlag=0;

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser);
$table= mysql_select_db('storagedb',$conn);

//************************** Request Table (Insertion)***************************

$getUser_sql=" INSERT INTO request VALUES (6,$serverVariable,1,0)";
$result=mysql_query($getUser_sql,$conn);


//************************** Request Table (Selection)**************************

//$ReceivedFlag="SELECT ReceivedFlag FROM request";
//$ReadFlag="SELECT ReadFlag FROM request";

while(($ReceivedFlag==1) && ($ReadFlag==0))
{

    $postUser_sql= "SELECT Message FROM request";
    $result1=mysql_query($postUser_sql,$conn);

    echo "<TABLE BORDER=4>"; 
    echo "<TR><TH>Message</TH></TR>";

     // format results by row 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
    {
       $Message = $row["Message"]; 
       echo "<TR><TD>$Message</TD></TR>"; 
    } 

   echo "Response</TABLE>";

    $query = "UPDATE request SET ReadFlag=1 WHERE ReceivedFlag=1";
    $result2=mysql_query($query,$conn);
}

//-------------- post the server variable to the other client -----------------------

$r = new HttpRequest('http://localhost/form.php', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$r->addPostFields(array('user' => $Message ));

try {
    echo $r->send()->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}


?>
```

---

I used the database as a buffer since I am working on different sessions which is  between the .VXML and first .php or the first .php and second .php

The form.php contains the following which just display a white page and doesn't print
the variable that is coming from the first .php:

```
<?php

$clientVariable=$_POST['Message']; //to print out the data
print ($clientVariable);
?>
```

So what I have to do in order to receive the variable correctly and display it in the second php?

I appreciate your help.

Regards,
Heba

Answer (score 0):

If your variable contains sensitive data, I would use a session. If not, you can simply use GET:

Using a session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myvariable'] = 'Insert variable here';
```

Then in php2:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myvariable'];
```

Or you can use GET:

```
header("Location: /php2.php?myvar=insertcontent");
```

Then in php2:

```
echo $_GET['myvar'];
```

Comment: It does. PHP sessions normally store the data server-side and place a cookie containing the session ID on the user's computer. Therefore, it doesn't require a protocol that supports state.